# Difference b/w cancel(true) and cancel(false) in AsyncTask Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to cancel AsyncTask using `cancel(Boolean)` method. when we use
`cancel(false)` and `cancel(true)`.

```
public final boolean cancel (boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#cancel(boolean)):

> boolean: true if the thread executing this task should be interrupted; otherwise, in-progress tasks are allowed to complete.

Answer (score 1):

When cancelling an AsyncTask you have to deal with the cancellation process of your task manually. By providing `false` you tell that the thread executing this task should not be interrupted and should finish its work.